# Access default value of a Python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

Is there any way to access the default value of a Python dictionary key after it is has been set to some value? Example:

```
mydict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
mydict.get('c', 3) # gives 3.
mydict['c'] = 10
# Is there any function such that func(mydict, 'c') gives 3
```

I looked up Python docs and also stack overflow, but could not find any solution.

Comment: You never set the value of `c` to `3` -- that value was never stored in the dictionary, so there's no way to retrieve it. You provided it as the default value to the `get` method, which means, "if the named key doesn't exist in the dictionary, return this value instead".

Comment: You *may* be interested in the [`setdefault` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=setdefault#dict.setdefault).